# (Nginx location regex issue) Need regex that matches either specific file extensions OR no extension

Tags: regex, nginx-location

I need a Nginx location regex that matches either specific file extensions (like html, css, js) OR no extension. A trailing slash should not matter. For example, `https://example.com/blah`, `https://example.com/blah.css`, `https://example.com/blah.css/`, and `https://example.com/.hidden-dir/blah.css` should all pass, but `https://example.com/blah.xx` and `https://example.com/blah.xx/` should fail. The path that it needs to traverse to get to the file can have any extension, because only the file itself matters.

Comment: Will you please show us what you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I came up with. It seems to work, minus the requirement that a trailing slash at the end shouldn't matter. If someone else can come up with a better solution, let me know.

```
# file extensions
location ~ [^\/]*\.[^\/]*$ {
  location ~* (?<=\.html|\.css|\.js)$ {
    # process request
  }
  return 404;
}

# the rest (i.e. no file extensions)
location / {
  # process request
}
```